# Invalid initializer member declarator C# LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I have XML and need parse it and create objects via LINQ

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <Books>         
   <Book> 
    <ID> number </ID>
    <DateCreated> date </DateCreated>  
    <Pages>  
     <Page>      
        <PageID> string </PageID>  
        <PageNumber> number </PageNumber> 
     </Page>     

    <!-- ... more Page nodes here if present ...     --> 
    </Pages>     
  </Book> 
   <!-- ... more Book nodes here ...     --> 
</Books>
```

Classes:

```
public class BooksResponse
    {
        public Book[] Book_Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Book
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string DateCreated { get; set; }
        public Page[] Pages { get; set; }
    }

    public class Page
    {
        public string PageID { get; set; }
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

and my code:

```
var booksResponse = xDocument
                            .Elements("Books")
                            .Select(x => new BooksResponse
                            {
                                Book_Items = x.Elements("Book")
                                .Select(c => new Book
                                {
                                    DateCreated = (string)c.Element("DateCreated"),
                                    ID = (int)c.Element("ID"),
                                    Pages => c.Elements("Pages")
                                    .Select(y => new Page
                                    {
                                        PageID = (string)y.Element("PageID"),
                                        PageNumber = (int)y.Element("PageNumber"),

                                    }).ToArray()

                                }).ToArray()

                            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

and near code Pages => c.Elements("Pages")

error:

Invalid initializer member declarator.

What I'm doing wrong, how to fix that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps you meant `Pages = c.Elements("Pages")...` (notice = instead of =>)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your XML, the correct syntax would be

```
Pages = c.Descendants("Page")
.Select(y => new Page
{
    PageID = (string)y.Element("PageID"),
    PageNumber = (int)y.Element("PageNumber"),

}).ToArray()
```

As already pointed out, first fix the `=>` to `=`. Now, Element `Pages` do not have elments `PageID` and `PageNumber`. They are under the node `Page`. To get the list of `Page` nodes, you can use `Descendants("Page")`, as they are not direct child element of `Book`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XmlSerializer`

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BooksResponse));
BooksResponse books = (BooksResponse)xs.Deserialize(responseStream);
```

Add attributes to your class `BooksResponse`

```
[XmlRoot("Books")]
public class BooksResponse
{
    [XmlElement("Book")]
    public Book[] Book_Items { get; set; }
}
```

It works on given xml.